# Sufficient conditions for $abc+def \leq 0$

Tags: inequality

Consider some real numbers $a,b,c,d,e,f$ satisfying the following relations:
$$
\begin{cases}
(ac)+(df)\leq 0\\
c+f=1\\
c\in [0,1]\\
f\in [0,1]\\
b\in [0.5,1]\\
e\in [0.5,1]\\
\end{cases}
$$
I would like to know if these conditions imply
$$
(1) \quad (abc)+(def) \leq 0
$$
If $a$ and $d$ are both negative, (1) clearly holds. Hence, I have tried to focus on a worst-case scenario where, for instance, $a\geq 0$ (and, hence, $d\leq 0)$. Under this scenario, I could not find a counterexample to (1), but I am not sure if this is indeed the case and how to formally (dis)prove it.

**Update**: as shown in a comment below, (1) is **not** an implication of the above conditions. To understand better, I would like to know if something change when I turn some of the above conditions into strict inequalities (just to see if the problem is only at the boundaries):
$$
\begin{cases}
(ac)+(df)< 0\\
c+f=1\\
c\in [0,1]\\
f\in [0,1]\\
b\in (0.5,1]\\
e\in (0.5,1]\\
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$abc+def = (ac+df)b - bdf+def = (ac+df)b + df(e-b)$ and $abc+def = (ac+df)e -ace+abc = (ac+df)e + ac(b-e)$, so you add both of them now:
$$2(abc+def) = (ac+df)(b+e) + (ac-df)(b-e).$$

So, if the above may not hold when $(ac-df)(b-e)$ is "large" positive. If we take $b = 1$ and $e = 0.5 + \varepsilon,$ then we just need:
$$\dfrac{ac-df}{-(ac+df)}>\dfrac{3+2\varepsilon}{1-2\varepsilon}.$$
This should be achieved rather easily while taking $c=f=\frac 12$ and let's take  $a>0>d$, with $a+d<0.$ Let $d\to -d$ to make it positive, so we need:
$$\dfrac{d+a}{d-a}>\dfrac{3+2\varepsilon}{1-2\varepsilon}$$
and $d>a.$ So just take $a = 1$ and $d = 1.1$, which gives us:
$$21>\dfrac{3+2\varepsilon}{1-2\varepsilon},$$ which is plenty. In your original formulation, it is $a = 1, d = -1.1, c = f = \frac 12, e = \frac 12+\varepsilon, b = 1$ for which we have:
$$2(abc + def) =1 -1.1 \varepsilon -0.55 = 0.45 - 1.1\varepsilon > 0 $$
for example for $\varepsilon = 0.3.$